# Проблема с настройкой pyqt в pycharm

Tags: python, pyqt5, pycharm

Пытаюсь настроить `pyqt5` в `pycharm 2020.2.1`.

Сначала установила `pyqt5` так:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Затем установила `tools` так:

```
pip install PyQT5-tools
```

После воспользовалась [этой](https://cucumbler.ru/blog/articles/nastrojka-pycharm-dlja-raboty-s-bibliotekoj-pyqt5.html) инструкцией, потом, когда вылезла такая ошибка:

"This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

установила `Anaconda3` и воспользовалась [этой](https://geekbrains.ru/topics/6304) инструкцией.

Теперь ошибка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо, нужно добавить в переменные среды еще какой-то путь, чтобы все заработало, но не могу понять какой :(

Если запускать дизайнер напрямую (лежит в пути `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin\designer.exe`)
вылетает все та же ошибка.

Может, стоит переустановить оба пакета, но других версий?

P.S. После проведения манипуляций с удалением/установкой разных версий перестали работать программы, до этого напрямую использовавшие pyqt - RadeonSettings, mediaget. Что делатб...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась удалением всех установленных модулей и (что очень важно) удалением всех новых переменных среды, которые были добавлены в процессе настройки, а затем установкой через `pip` пакетов `pyqt5` и `pyqt5-tools`.